# Hbase .log files

Tags: hbase

My HBASE runs in pseudo-distributed mode and the version is hbase-0.98.5 . When I list the hbase files in HDFS I am not able to view the .logs folder,I had created few tables in HBASE .I am confused  where is the WAL edits stored? Or is there any problem with my installation. I can see a WAL folder in the files listed.Is that the same as the.logs folder .Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from 0.96 the /hbase directory layout was changed
/hbase/.logs is now /hbase/WAL
/hbase/tableName is now /hbase/data/default/tableName
and more...

Comment: Yes, I can see the table and its related regions in /hbase/data/default/tableName . Thank you for the help