# Loading a csv file to Apache Phoenix table and logging rows of invalid data

Tags: apache, csv, logging, load, apache-phoenix

I follow the instruction on the link below to load csv data into a Phoenix data using MapReduce.
https://phoenix.apache.org/bulk_dataload.html

I loaded a small file successfully. However, when I tried to load a multi-million-record file, I got "illegal data" error and no record was loaded. I then bypassed the error using the "--ignore-errors" option and loaded the file, and as I expected, not all records were loaded according to the table records count.

I read somewhere that Phoenix or HBase is heavily logged. I wonder whether those errors were logged or some Phoenix configuration I need to do to enable the logging.

Also, the above page briefly describes the tool - org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool. Where can I find the full documentation?

Comment: I understand Phoenix is just a sql wrapper around HBase. So HBase log files may be what I need. Where can I find HBase log files?

Comment: Does this help to retrieve log files?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925865/hbase-log-files